# How to refresh a filter data extension using automation?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, automationstudio

I want to refresh a filtered data extension everyday, I have a main data extension "abc" and a filtered data extension named "worldwide" which is filtered from "abc"

What I have already done is,

Step 1 - Created datafilter using "abc" DE
Step 2 - Created automation and configured filter activity
Step 3 - Run the automation
Step 4 - New data extension "pqr" created from the automation, which is in the "abc" data extension folder

My question is,

Q1 - Whether I am doing it correctly? Do I just have to schedule the automation right?

Q2 - If I move the "pqr" data extension to another folder, will it be a problem for automation and refresh, it will refresh everyday?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great questions and luckily you are pretty much there already.

Q1 - Yes you are doing it 100% correctly.  You are spot on for the full process and by scheduling the automation, you will refresh during every instance run to ensure the data is up to date.

Q2 - The location in the folder structure will not affect the automation/interactions as they are based off the external key or unique identifier of the interaction, and not the directory location.